# Turn off gzip compression for one virtual host

Tags: php, nginx, gzip

I'm running into a problem where I *think* PHP deprecation errors are causing the headers to be malformed, causing a 330 error. If I disable error reporting for E_DEPRECATION, the error disappears, so I'm fairly certain it's related to that.

On our production site, that's not a problem, since we're not showing any errors anyway. But in our dev environment, I need to be able to see the errors in order to fix them.

We're using nginx with two different virtual hosts. What I would like to know is if there's a way to disable gzip compression on one of those virtual hosts, so that I can see whether or not that's the issue.

I'm not a server admin, I just play one on TV, so please go easy on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your

> Server {

declaration, just put the line

```
gzip off;
```

Alternatively, you can put the same line under your

> location / {

line, if you want to only cover part of the virtual host.